# When to parametrize and use $x = \cos t$ vs just $x = t$

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between using $x = \cos t$ and $x = t$ for parametrizing equations.

For example, in this question

[image]

We use $x = \cos t, \ y = \sin t$.

However, in this question

> Find the work done by the force $F = y\mathbf i + x\mathbf j + z\mathbf k$ in moving from $(-1,2,5)$ to $(1,0,1)$ on C the curve of intersection of the paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$ and the plane $x + y = 1$.

Here in the solution we used $x = t$, but I don't understand why we didn't use $\cos t$ since we have a curve $z= x^2 + y^2$.

Comment: It all depends on the curve you're integrating along.  In this case, the curve is the intersection of two surfaces.  Letting $x=t$ is just a starting point for working out the other two variables in terms of $t$.  From the second equation, we get straight away that if $x=t$, then $y=1-t$.  Then, from the first equation, we get $z=2t^2-2t+1$.  We didn't need anything complicated here.  Notice that we could have started by letting $y=t$ instead - there is no canonical choice.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible answers. It often is possible to parameterize either way. In your "Example 1" you could also have used

$$x=t,\ y=\sqrt{1-t^2}$$

But that has a square root, which can cause difficulties in integrations. Moreover, the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is undefined at the endpoints $x=\pm 1$ which can cause further difficulties. The advantages of this parameterization is that it avoids the transcendental functions sine and cosine. In this particular problem the sine and cosine become easier, but that would not be the case in other, similar problems.

In your paraboloid problem, the desired curve is just that, so if $x=t$ then $y$ is an easier function of $t$ than a square root. In this problem, $x=t$ is easier.

There is another reason. In the first problem, $x$ is bounded: $-1\le x\le 1$. Cosine is also bounded, so it works there. In the second problem, $x$ is not bounded, so a cosine does not work here. In such cases you may use the reciprocal, secant, or perhaps tangent or hyperbolic cosine.

In other words, use what works and is easiest for the particular problem.